# compare today's data with same day last week

Tags: sql, date, calculation, domo

I am looking for a date function to compare data today vs lastweek sameday . e.g Wednesday this week vs Wednesday last week. I am particularly looking to write in Domo (BI TOOL) but any language(sql ) would be appreciated.

Thanks

I can not find a way to write formula in Domo .

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own sets of functions.)

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from your_table y1
left join your_table y2 on y1.date -7 = y2.date
```

Comment: there is no as such function to resolve this only the methods

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE DAY_OF_WEEK(your_date_column) = DAY_OF_WEEK(CURRENT_DATE)
  AND DATE_DIFF(your_date_column, CURRENT_DATE, WEEK) = 1
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting to compare aggregate values between the two dates?

This would give you two rows, one for today (Thursday) and another for last Thursday:

```sql
SELECT date_col, SUM(something), AVG(something_else)
FROM your_tabl
WHERE date_col = CURRENT_DATE
   OR date_col = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
GROUP BY date_col
```

I have used the functions documented on [Beast Mode Functions Reference Guide](https://domo-support.domo.com/s/article/360043429933?language=en_US).